# get filename and extension and remove query string using substring

Tags: c#, substring

Hiee guys,

I have several image urls from which i download the data and save it in db. I use `(imageurl.Split('/'))[(imageurl.Split('/').Length) - 1];` to create the filename.

Problem is,there are some urls which contains query string. due to which filenames i get for them have pattern `imgname.img_type_extension?somefield=somevalue`

How can i get filename.extension leaving query string from above substring??

Thanks for stopping by...

Comment: Did you try Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()?

Comment: i have my urls coming from database and not from pages

Comment: I never assume it comes from eleswhere.

Comment: Do you store the full path of the file in the DB?

Comment: yes onam.i store fullpath of images in DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
var fNameWithQuery = (imageurl.Split('/'))[(imageurl.Split('/').Length) - 1];
//get first string from array created by splitting substring on occurence of '?'
var fNameAndExt = fNameWithQuery.Split('?')[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not let the UriBuilder do the parsing for you?

```
var url = new UriBuilder("http://x.com/xyz/imgname.img_type_extension?somefield=somevalue");
string filename = Path.GetFileName(url.Path);
```

Comment: Or perhaps better yet, why not just let `Uri` do the parsing? My guess is newing up a simple, immutable `Uri` type would be more performant, but maybe not...?

Answer (score 5):

```
var path = imageurl.Split('?')[0];
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

EDIT : for file name WITH extension just use another method from `Path`

```
    var path = imageurl.Split('?')[0];
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Comment: Actually like this one. Didn't know about System.IO.Path.. learn something new everyday!

Comment: I was under the impression that you needed file name and extension, not file name alone ;)

Comment: @nakiya good point - I thought i saw "filename without extension" in the question :P

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```
    string imgUrl = @"C:\blah.jpg"; //Loaded from DB
    System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(imgUrl);
    string fileName = f.Name.Split('.')[0];
```